# How to get Centos installation date from text file

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, centos6, centos5

I found with this command I can get the Centos installation date.

```
ls -lctd --time-style=+"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" /etc | tail -1 | awk '{print $6, $7}'
```

But in my case I need to get this value from /proc or some other text file which I can read with Java.
Is there any text file that I can use for reading this value?

Answer (score 1):

> But in my case I need to get this value from /proc or some other text file which I can read with Java. Is there any text file that I can use for reading this value?

As far as I know, No.

However you should be able to do the equivalent of that "shell" command using Java 7 file attributes.  Specifically, [`PosixFileAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributes.html) allows you to access the creation timestamp.  (Here is a tutorial on the Java 7 file attributes API ... http://andreinc.net/2013/12/05/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-file-attributes/)

I should also point out that using the creation timestamp of "/etc" as a proxy for the installation date / time is a bit dubious.  That directory could have been restored from a backup ... or the timestamp could have been changed using `touch` or equivalent.

---

**UPDATE**

The alternative solution you found involved running the external command `rpm -qi basesystem`.  You *could* run that command from Java using `ProcessBuilder` etc ... and then parse the output.  However, the `rpm` command is using information from the RPM databases, and I'm not aware of a Java library that would allow you to access that info directly ... without a great deal of extra effort.

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - I think I've answered that.

Comment: From this port http://kairo.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/checking-the-install-dat-of-linux-operation-system-red-hat-not-official-but-usefull/ I found that maybe there is a better way to find to OS installation date. How I can get this data with Java?